# Magnetic field above, below and everywhere outside the solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields

I have read many times at a lot of websites, books etc. that magnetic field outside a solenoid is zero because their components cancel out...,others say that magnetic field is too weak outside to be considered because of the ideal infinite solenoid. Firstly, which components are they talking about that cancel out each other? Well I do understand that the perpendicular magnetic fields of adjacent circular loops cancel out because yes they are opposite but what are those outside components in case of magnetic fields outside?

And, what about the magnetic field above and below the solenoid? If we consider the solenoid made of many circular loops (which it actually is!),then the way we add up the axial magnetic fields inside the solenoid, shouldn't we do the same for the above and below ones? Yes I do understand that the magnetic fields above and below are opposite but since they are not interacting with each other, how can we sum them up to zero?

People say that when you consider the solenoid to be infinite, there's no path for the fields to go outside but again, the solenoid is made of many circular loops and each circular loop is contributing to inside AS WELL AS outside. Correct me if any of my assumptions is wrong. I m really confused about this.
[image: well this is what my textbook writes]

Comment: So you know about magnetic field from a current ring... Just integrate the field from a bunch of such (displaced) rings that together make up a solenoid, and that's your answer. What is the problem? A good start would be a diagram, equations you are solving & boundary conditions. A shortcut would be to start with the magnetic field due to current loop at an arbitrary location

Comment: @cryo i think you misunderstood my question. I am not asking how to calculate magnetic field due to a solenoid, I am asking why is the field outside the solenoid zero. And secondly I didn't understand your way to calculate the field. Yes I do know how to calculate the field for a current ring but it depends on what point are you calculating. Can we generalize it just like you have mentioned?

Comment: unless your solenoid is bent into a torus, or you try to consider infinite solenoid, the field outside will not be zero. The answer to 'why' is 'because that's what calculations show'.

Comment: @cryo I have been taught the magnetic field of the solenoid by ampere's circuital law and as far as I know, ampere's law doesn't really work for a current ring

Comment: @ cryo Well that's my question even when we consider it infinite why would it be zero. I mean each circular ring does contribute for outside as well as inside, so why are we cutting out the outside ones? It would be a great help if you could show those calculations

Comment: Field outside the solenoid is not zero strictly speaking, just much weaker than inside, and the difference gets larger and larger as you make solenoid longer. So if the field inside is finite, the field outside should be going to zero, or you count field outside as finite, and field inside will tend to infinity. #

Comment: What do you mean Ampere's law doesn't work for current ring? $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}$
, for magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ and current density $\mathbf{J}$ at all times in vacuum, as long as currents/fields are steady/static. Have you consulted any textbooks? Jackson (Classical Electrodynamics, Chapter 5) has an exhaustive treatment of a current loop, but you end up with a pile of special functions. Griffiths (Introduction to Electrodynamics) shows a simpler but more limited approach.

Comment: @cryo I have edited my question to add the picture of what my textbook has written about this. I am really sorry..I got confused but yes ampere's law does work for a current ring but as I said before...magnetic field at different points will be different. In my book, they have calculated the axial magnetic field by using the biot savart law as
B=constant of permeability times IR²/2(x²+R²)³/² and magnetic field at the centre of the ring as:B=constant of permiability times I/2R and in this picture, they have written that ampere's law can't be applied in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118408/discussion-between-chahak-and-cryo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ form a steady current $\mathbf{J}$ you have to solve

$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}
$$

A suitable solution is given by (see vector potential and Green functions in Jackson):

$$
\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=-\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int d^3r'\,\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r'}\right)\times\boldsymbol{\nabla}\frac{1}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int d^3r'\,\,\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r'}\right)\times\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|^3}
$$

This is the [Biot-Savart law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law)

Next, you need to parametrize. Lets say that position of the observer is $\mathbf{r}=(X,\,Y,\,Z)^T=\left(R\cos\Phi,\,R\sin\Phi,\,Z\right)^T$ in Cartesian coordinates, and $\{R,\,\Phi,\,Z\}$ in Cyllindrical coorinates. The position that you are integrating with respect to is $\mathbf{r}'=(x',\,y',\,z')^T=\left(\rho\cos\phi,\,\rho\sin\phi,\,z'\right)^T$.

We assume that current density is going clock-wise around z-axis at radius $\mathcal{R}$:

$$
\mathbf{J}\left(\mathbf{r'}\right)=I\,\left(\begin{array}\\-\sin\phi\\\quad\cos\phi\\\quad0\end{array}\right)\,\delta\left(\rho-\mathcal{R}\right)/\rho
$$

Where $I$ is a constant with units of current (as opposed to current density). Assume that solenoid is aligned with z-axis and has a length of $L$, so that $z'=-L/2\dots L/2$.

Finally
$$
\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|^3=\left(\left(Z-z'\right)^2+\left(R\cos\Phi-\rho\cos\phi\right)^2+\left(R\sin\Phi-\rho\sin\phi\right)^2\right)^{3/2}
$$

So the integral for magnetic field will be:

$$
\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=
\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\int^{L/2}_{-L/2} dz'\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\,\left[\frac{\left(\begin{array}\\-\sin\phi\\\quad\cos\phi\\\quad0\end{array}\right)\times\left(\begin{array}\\R\cos\Phi-\mathcal{R}\cos\phi\\R\sin\Phi-\mathcal{R}\sin\phi\\Z-z'\end{array}\right)}{\left(\left(Z-z'\right)^2+\left(R\cos\Phi-\mathcal{R}\cos\phi\right)^2+\left(R\sin\Phi-\mathcal{R}\sin\phi\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}\right]
$$

Evaluating cross-product and setting $\Phi=0$ (cyllindrical symmetry):

$$
\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=
\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\int^{L/2}_{-L/2} dz'\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\,\left[\frac{
{}
\left(\begin{array}\\
\cos\phi\cdot\left(Z-z'\right) \\
\sin\phi\cdot\left(Z-z'\right) \\
\mathcal{R}-R\cos\left(\phi\right)
\end{array}\right)
{}
}{\left(\left(Z-z'\right)^2+R^2+\mathcal{R}^2-2R\mathcal{R}\cos\phi\right)^{3/2}}\right]
$$

So now you may start to appreciate why not many places give a full expression for magnetic field from a solenoid - the integral is really annoying.

The simplest limit to consider is $\mathcal{R}\to0$, in which case:

$$
\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)=
\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi}\int^{L/2}_{-L/2} dz'\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\,\left[\frac{
{}
\left(\begin{array}\\
\cos\phi\cdot\left(Z-z'\right) \\
\sin\phi\cdot\left(Z-z'\right) \\-R\cos\left(\phi\right)
\end{array}\right)
{}
}{\left(\left(Z-z'\right)^2+R^2\right)^{3/2}}\right]=\mathbf{0}
$$

by the virtue of $\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\cos\phi=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\sin\phi=0$. Clearly $\mathcal{R}\to 0$ only makes sense for $R>0$ (outside the solenoid).

Limit for infinitely long solenoid $L\to\infty$ is more subtle because you are integrating with respect to $z'$. I would suggest setting $Z=0$ (infinite solenoid, so it does not matter how far along it you are) and then using the fact that integrand will be odd in $z'$ to show that $B_x=B_y=0$. For $B_z$ you will have to evaluate an integral of type

$$
\int^{2\pi}_{0} d\phi \frac{a-\cos{\phi}}{\left|b-c\cdot\cos\phi\right|^{3/2}}
$$

My mathematical package is taking too long to evaluate it, so I will leave it as is. You can always write a small numerical calculator to test. Otherwise, try expanding the integrand in series of small $c$ before integration

Answer (score 0):

As for the field being small outside of a solenoid, consider that the field from a flat sheet of current tends to be uniform.  The field from the near side of the solenoid is opposed by that from the current on the far side.  To find the field at any point near a given solenoid, it is not too difficult to set up a numeric integration of the formula from Biot-Savart where you are adding the vector components from each short segment of each current carrying loop.